# Why is my HTML form inside a jQuery-UI dialog not submitting?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

This is the code of an HTML form as shown by Firebug:

```
<form action="http://localhost/home/newuser" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="48" name="user_id">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

And here's some jQuery code bound to it:

```
$('.popup .newuser form').live('submit', function()
{
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(data)
    {
     // handle response
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, when I click on the "Next" button, what happens is that the text field shows a combobox of previously entered values (a Firefox feature). There is no HTML request showing up on Firebug's Network tab, and breakpoints in the jQuery listener are not hit.

It feels like I'm missing something really obvious...

**Update:** I've realized that something even stranger is going on: I cannot *enter* anything in the text field either via keyboard. I can only select the previous values from the Firefox combobox. And after doing that, I can't even select the text in the box.

Comment: Can you give the response Code, which you have commented out (// handle response) ?

Comment: I don´t sure about your bug. I think you need any ext on you action. you use html, php, jsp or .do? action="http://localhost/home/newuser.php" I hope it help you

Comment: Sounds like either the `live` isn't successfully wiring up to the event, or maybe the selector has an issue?  I know it sounds obvious, but are the `popup` and `newuser` classed tags surrounding the form?  Is it possible that `popup` and `newuser` are sibling classes (i.e. `<div class="popup newuser">`)?  If that's the case, then the selector should be `$('.popup.newuser ...')` without the space.

Comment: @DRP96: since it's not being executed, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @ataddeini: I just put a breakpoint into the jQuery live() function, and it was hit, and on the correct DOM element.

Comment: Can you try `on` instead of `live`?

Comment: @SelimOber: doesn't make a difference, the problem stays the same.

Comment: O_o @ your update.  Can't enter anything?  That's a little... fishy.

Comment: @Xyan Ewing: definitely - I'm increasingly convinced that something else is capturing keyboard and mouse events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem had nothing to do with jQuery or Javascript; instead it lay in the CSS, where a DIV containing the form had a z-index of 1, and was itself contained in a jQuery-UI dialog, which the framework gave a z-index of 1001. Apparently this caused the inner DIV (and thus the form) to not receive any keyboard or mouse events at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://localhost/home/newuser" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="48" name="user_id" />
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Put / at the end of the input element

Comment: It's actually there in the HTML, what I have in the question is the normalized HTML shown by firebug

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `<form ... OnSubmit="yourfunction()"></form>` ?

Comment: Because the whole app is based on unobtrusively attached jQuery event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in a comment but it seems I don't yet have the privilege of doing so.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

**EDIT**

Separate your selectors with commas rather than spaces:

`$('form, .popup, .newuser')`

Hope that helps

Comment: Interesting - but looking at the jQuery code, I see that live() just forwards to on() anyway. And no, the callback is not triggered - it seems like no submit is actually happening.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it must have something to do with the selectors. I just set up pretty much identically and tested, didn't see anything in Firebug console, I changed the selector to just `$('form')` and I can see the POST requests straight away.

Comment: The selector works. The problems seems to be afterwards, events getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated now. For cross-browser support, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when you are using jQuery 1.7+ or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in lower versions.

.on() example :

```
$(document).on('submit', '.popup .newuser form', function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(data){
       // handle response
    });
    return false;
});
```

.delegate() example :

```
$(document).on('.popup .newuser form', 'submit', function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(data){
       // handle response
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Using on() makes no difference, and the callback is never executed.

Comment: Is the `.on()` not invoking or `.ajaxSubmit()` not invoking ?

Comment: is the action url `http://localhost/home/newuser` is of same domain or different ? This could happen if you are doing cross-domain AJAX request.

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript then you will be sure whether it is a cross-domain request.